# React app with Firebase User wont stay signed out / displaying user info wrong

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-hooks, firebase-authentication

Console.logs of currentUser[image]

I have a UserContext.js file which holds all of the useContext hooks. a Nav.js that displays some user info and a "Sign in" OR "Sign out" button. a Profile.js that displays user info. App.js that holds components and useContext.

Whats happening is if i sign in with a user everything gets displayed and i can navigate to various pages and the user information stays displayed. If i click Sign Out from the nav menu all of the user information instead of displaying “No User Info” shows empty fields on all the pages. And the “Sign Out” button appears again. I think this is happening because the UserContextProvider thats wrapping all of my components in App.js are calling auth.signout from the toggleUser function every time i navigate to a different page ? could i extract the toggleUser function out of the scope of UserContextProvider ? Or is something else happening?

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { UserContextProvider } from '../../../src/util/Context/UserContext'

import Navmenu from '../Nav/Nav';
import Home from '../../Pages/Home/Home';
import Signin from '../../Pages/Sign-in/Sign-in';
import Signup from '../../Pages/Sign-up/Sign-up';
import Profile from '../../Pages/Profile/Profile';
import Footer from '../Footer/Footer';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <UserContextProvider>
          <Navmenu />
          <hr className="p-0 m-0"></hr>
          <Routes>
            <Route exact path='/' element={<Home />} />
            <Route path='/signin' element={<Signin />} />
            <Route path='/signup' element={<Signup />} />
            <Route path='/profile' element={<Profile />} />
          </Routes>
          <Footer />
        </UserContextProvider>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  )
};

export default App;
```

UserContext.js

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { auth, createUserProfileDocument } from "../firebase/firebase.utils";

const UserContext = React.createContext(null);
const UserUpdateContext = React.createContext();

export const useUserContext = () => {
    // useContext hook 
    return useContext(UserContext);
}

export const useUserContextUpdate = () => {
    // useContext hook 
    return useContext(UserUpdateContext)
}

export const UserContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [currentUser, setUser] = useState(null);
    let unsubscribeFromAuth = null;

    useEffect(() => {
        unsubscribeFromAuth = auth.onAuthStateChanged(async userAuth => {
            if (userAuth) {
                const userRef = await createUserProfileDocument(userAuth);

                userRef.onSnapshot(snapShot => {
                    setUser({
                        id: snapShot.id,
                        ...snapShot.data()
                    });
                });
            } else {
                setUser({ currentUser: userAuth })
            }
        });

        return () => {
            unsubscribeFromAuth();
        };
    }, [])
    

    const toggleUser = () => {
        auth.signOut()
        .then((currentUser) => {
            setUser(null)
        })
        .catch(e => console.log('There was a error:'(e)))
    }

    return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={currentUser} >
            <UserUpdateContext.Provider value={toggleUser} >
                {children}
            </UserUpdateContext.Provider >
        </UserContext.Provider >
    )
};
```

Nav.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './Nav.css';

import { useUserContext, useUserContextUpdate } from '../../../src/util/Context/UserContext';
import { auth } from '../../util/firebase/firebase.utils';

import { Nav, Navbar, NavDropdown } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Bell from './img/Bell.svg';
import Message from './img/Message.svg';
import Userprofile from './img/Userprofile.svg';
import Aboutme from './img/Aboutme.svg';
import Findfriends from './img/Findfriends.svg';
import Accountsetting from './img/Accountsetting.svg';

const Navmenu = ({  }) => {
    const currentUser = useUserContext();
    const toggleUser = useUserContextUpdate();

    return (
        <div className='tc f3'>
            <Navbar bg='light' expand='lg'>
                <a className="text-decoration-none" href="/">
                    <Navbar.Brand className="mx-2 mx-lg-5">Yelp-Clone</Navbar.Brand>
                </a>
                <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
                <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                    <hr></hr>
                    <Nav className='ml-5'>
                        <Nav.Link className='link-font' href="#home">Write a Review</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link className='link-font' href="#link">Events</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link className='link-font' href="#link">Talk</Nav.Link>
                    </Nav>
                    <div className="d-flex flex-row justify-content-lg-center align-items-center ml-auto">
                        <img className='nav-img me-2' src={Message}></img>
                        <img className='nav-img me-2' src={Bell}></img>
                        <img className='nav-img-lrg' src={Userprofile}></img>
                        <NavDropdown className='custom-dropdown-class me-3' id="basic-nav-dropdown">
                            <div className="d-flex flex-row">
                                <img className='nav-img-sml me-2' src={Userprofile}></img>
                                <div className="d-flex flex-column">
                                    {
                                        currentUser ?
                                            <span>{currentUser.displayName}</span>
                                            :
                                            <span>No User Found</span>
                                    }
                                    {
                                        currentUser ?
                                            <span>{currentUser.email}</span>
                                            :
                                            <span>No Email Found</span>
                                    }
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <NavDropdown.Divider />
                            <div className="link-wrapper my-1">
                                <img className="link-font-sml me-2 inline-block" src={Aboutme}></img><a className="link-font-sml"><Link className="link-font-sml" to="/profile">About Me</Link></a>
                            </div>
                            <div className="link-wrapper my-1">
                                <img className="link-font-sml me-2 inline-block" src={Findfriends}></img><span className="link-font-sml">Find Friends</span>
                            </div>
                            <div className="link-wrapper my-1">
                                <img className="link-font-sml me-2 inline-block" src={Accountsetting}></img><span className="link-font-sml">Account Settings</span>
                            </div>
                            <NavDropdown.Divider />
                            <NavDropdown.Item className="p-0">
                                <div className="text-center options">
                                    {
                                        currentUser ?
                                            <a className="option" onClick={toggleUser}>
                                                Sign Out
                                            </a>
                                            :
                                            <a><Link className="option" to="/signin">Sign In</Link></a>
                                    }
                                </div>
                            </NavDropdown.Item>
                        </NavDropdown>
                    </div>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Navbar>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Navmenu
```

Comment: Does `setUser(null)` get called in `toggleUser`? Have you verified/validated that `currentUser` is reset to `null`? What other debugging have you done to see what, if anything, is still updating the `currentUser` state?

Comment: Yeah it looks like currentUser does get set to null if i console log currentUser in Nav and in UserContext after toggleUser function i get back an {currentUser: null} and the string null from both

Comment: Ok, and yet the sign out button is still displaying? You are still seeing the previous `currentUser` information?

Comment: Yeah the Sign Out button reappears even though no user information is displayed and im no longer seeing currentUser information that i previously saw in console.logs

Comment: So if you drop a `console.log(currentUser)` or set a debugger/breakpoint in `Nav` *just* after `const currentUser = useUserContext();` what is the value after signing out? You mention a string null, do you mean `"null"`, or is it *actually* `null`? It seems that the `current` user is still *some* defined truthy object in `Nav`.

Comment: I included a couple screenshots showing the result of console.log(currentUser) after  initial sign-in while user information is displayed, and after sign-out while no user information is displayed but Sign Out button reappears.

Comment: I mean actually null

Comment: In the `UserContextProvider` try setting `currentUser` to just `null` in the else branch, i.e. `setUser(userAuth)` or `setUser(null)` when there's no truthy `userAuth` value. `{currentUser: null }` is a defined, truthy object with a null `currentUser` property.

Comment: Its also important to note that if i sign out from any page inside of whatever page i sign out from i get back user information displaying. Once i go back to home sign-in or sign-up pages it goes back to blank....except for the profile page that will still show it, until i go to home  sign-in or sign-up then profile wont show either

Comment: @ Drew Reese setting setUser(null) in the else clause of UserContextProvider worked!

Comment: @DrewReese I'm lost on how an object is truthy though

Comment: A very simple test, try `!!{}` in your console and see the result. [Falsey values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) are `false`, `0`, `-0`, `0n`, empty strings, `null`, `undefined`, `NaN`. Note that empty object `{}` and empty arrays `[]` are not on the list, they are defined values. Truthy values are all values ***not*** defined as falsey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to venture a guess as to why users don't stay "logged out" it is because of the inner subscription in the `useEffect` not being unsubscribed to as well. It can still update the `user` state.

Ensure you also reset the `currentUser` state to null when there'e a falsey `userAuth` value in the `onAuthStateChanged` callback.

```
useEffect(() => {
  let unsubscribeFromAuth = null;
  let unsubscribeFromSnapshot = null;

  unsubscribeFromAuth = auth.onAuthStateChanged(async userAuth => {
    if (userAuth) {
      const userRef = await createUserProfileDocument(userAuth);

      unsubscribeFromSnapshot = userRef.onSnapshot(snapShot => {
        setUser({
          id: snapShot.id,
          ...snapShot.data()
        });
      });
    } else {
      setUser(null); // <-- reset user state
    }
  });

  return () => {
    unsubscribeFromAuth();
    unsubscribeFromSnapshot();
  };
}, []);
```

Comment: Hi Drew, thanks for the answer. this unfortunately did not work, i really think its something wrong with the toggleUser function

Comment: @Halp_am_stuck Hmm, ok. What makes you think it's the sign out function?

Comment: I think because if i do an initial login from the sign-in page im free to navigate around various pages and everything renders how it should with user display names and emails. Its not until i click "Sign Out" button that things start not working